# What causes Unauthorized access error in Master Data services web application?

Tags: sql-server, master-data-services

I have a brand new sql server, IIS and Master Data services installation. The installation went okay, but when I access MDS via the browser, I don't see any models or versions listed in "Model:" and "Version:" dropdowns on the home page for my database. Chrome dev tools gives this error "failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (unauthorized)", but I was able to log into the web app and see the home page. I am also able to log into the database directly, with the same username and password.

I've done the usual auth stuff (enable anonymous auth, ASP.NET impersonation, Form auth). Not sure what else to try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question touches on a few issues:

If it's a brand new installation, did you create a new model or deploy any old models? (Sys Admin>Manage>Models>'Add' or Sys Admin>Deployment on the web app tool). You will only see a model in the drop down if you Add a new model or deploy a package of an already created model.

You mention Chrome dev tools. MDS Web app runs on Silverlight, and Chrome does not support it. You need to use IE, or I found an older version of Firefox supporting Silverlight works fine.